# Jimp.read never runs callback and hangs up

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot, and one of my commands resizes a requested image and sends it. When I run the command though, it just hangs up with no error message. If I take out the callback and run it normally, it sends, but sends the last image requested instead of the one that just was.

```
function resizeImg(id,_callback) {
            const img = Jimp.read('image.png')
                .then(img => {
                    return img
                        .resize(100,130)
                        .write('temp.png');
                    _callback();
                })
            .catch(console.error);
}

resizeImg(id,function() {
            var attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./temp.png')
            msg.channel.send('',attachment)
});
```

Comment: `.catch(console.error); > .catch(console.log(error));` Does that show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You call back is never reached because of the `return` statement that stops the execution.

```
function resizeImg(id, _callback) {
  Jimp.read('image.png').then(img => {
    const img = img.resize(100,130).write('temp.png');
    _callback(img);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
}

resizeImg(id, function(img) {
  var attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./temp.png')
  msg.channel.send('', attachment)
});
```

Try the code above. You can now access the img through a parameter in your callback.

Comment: Take a look at Promises with `async/await` syntax: https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async